# How can I prevent user from clicking the button twice, so that when the user closes the app and opens up he still can't click

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, swift2

How can I prevent user from clicking the button twice, so that when the user closes the app and opens up he will be taken to a different view controller? For now I understood how to prevent the user from clicking the button twice with this code:

```
/////// GO TO THE PARTY BUTTON  
@IBAction func sendSweet(sender: AnyObject) {
    // For disabling button
    self.login.enabled = false  ////  <---- THIS

    let sweet:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Going")
    sweet["userprofile"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    sweet["first_name"] = PFUser.currentUser()?["first_name"] as? String
    sweet["last_name"] = PFUser.currentUser()?["last_name"] as? String
    sweet["email"] = PFUser.currentUser()?["email"] as? String
    sweet["club"] = nameEnglish.text
    sweet["date"] = capital.text
    sweet["eventdetails"] = nameLocal.text

    sweet.saveInBackground()
```

When a user clicks on it once it works but if I close the app and open up again it still allows first click, and after first click I just want the user not to be able to click the button again at all and to take him to another view controller "saying you already clicked the button" and never be able to click the "first click" again.

It's basically an event app where you see what events are happening and choose which ones to go to. If you click Go once, I get the user name in parse, but I don't want him to click again because I just keep receiving the same name over and over again.

Comment: Maybe do a check in the setup of that button on whether the user has already said "Yes" to the event. If yes, don't show the button. Without more code we can only guess, but maybe you're re-enabling this button somewhere else? ViewWillAppear?

Answer (score 1):

The best way do it is creat a class that will contain all the events the user regestired for. So you will create a new parse class with a pointer to the user class. In the viewDidLoad() you can call a PFQuery to the registration class query where user equals PFUser.currentUser and then you can disable your button accordingly.

Thats the only way to do it In my opinion, because you have to think about senarios where users might have multiple devices accessing the same account. So it cannot be stored locally.